# Alternative to thread_local for calling legacy C code on OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, vtk

I have a mesh processing algorithm that calls vtkPointsProjectedHull multithreaded via high-level map-reduce (Qt's version).

If you look at the [source code of vtkPointsProjectedHull](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Common/DataModel/vtkPointsProjectedHull.cxx) you can see that it calls a free standing C-function and for that it uses a **static global variable** at line 27:

```
static double firstPt[3];
```

(You might be able to imagine how long it took to find this bug after I made the code multi-threaded...).

The layout of the class and free standing C-functions make it hard to move the static definition into a class variable. (I'm sure it is doable, but not straightforward).

The solution in VisualC++ is quite easy, I made a vtkPointsProjectedHullFixed.cxx with the single change being that the static variable is thread_local:

```
__declspec(thread) static double firstPt[3];
```

Now I am porting this code to OSX Clang. And thread local storage is explicitly disabled there.

Do I have to rewrite the whole vtkPointsProjectedHullFixed class to use a class variable? Or do you know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess as I cannot confirm at present, but you might find:

```
_Thread_local static double firstPt[3];
```

will work. Apple Clang does support C11 thread local, and `double` is a C type; what it doesn't support is C++ thread local which supports C++ types with constructors/destructors.

HTH

Edit: Confirmed `_Thread_local` works as expected with C code. Should work with C++ code, but only if the variable type is a C one (as `double` is).

Comment: It compiles, at the moment I have no time to do extended multithreading tests. But I guess if it compiles, it should also work as intended. Thanks!